# can't scroll after adding a transparent container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `PageView` with Stack children. those `Stack` widgets contain transparent containers that controlls the opacity level relative to the scroll position.

the expense is that now I am unable to scroll what's in the background. what  is the best way to add that layer and keep my backround scroll active.

Updating the Listview widget seems expensive as the opacity transion changes that is why I tried to keep it separate

I have something like this

```
Stack(children: [
                Scaffold(
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: ListView...,   // the listView I am trying to scroll
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                currIndex == 1 ? MainCardTransitionContainer() : Container(), // the layer with opacity 
              ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try IgnorePointer:

```
Stack(children: [
                Scaffold(
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: ListView...,   // the listView I am trying to scroll
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                currIndex == 1 ? IgnorePointer(ignoring: true, child:MainCardTransitionContainer(),) : Container(), // the layer with opacity 
              ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Stack(children: [
                currIndex == 1 ? MainCardTransitionContainer() : Container(), // the layer with opacity
                Scaffold(
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: ListView...,   // the listView I am trying to scroll
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
```

It's because the top widget of stack is kept at background and last widget is placed in foreground.

In short keep background element at top of stack

Comment: I know fam, by doing that though the opacity layer is no longer doing its use